# Get TransformableNode size in metres

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am setting my TransformableNode Size initially in Vector3. Then I scaled my TransformableNode. 
I want now the scaled TransformableNode size in metres nit in Vector3. 
Please help me in that.
I tried these but not getting any solution:

```
Vector3 vec = transformableNode.getLocalPosition();
Vector3 vector = transformableNode.getWorldPosition();
Vector3 vector31 = transformableNode.getWorldScale();
Vector3 vector32 = transformableNode.getLocalScale();
Log.e("Vector Local Position: ", String.valueOf(vec.x + " " + vec.y + " " + vec.z));
Log.e("Vector World Position: ", String.valueOf(vector.x + " " + vector.y + " " + vector.z));
Log.e("Vector World Scale: ", String.valueOf(vector31.x + " " + vector31.y + " " + vector31.z));
Log.e("Vector Local Scale: ", String.valueOf(vector32.x + " " + vector32.y + " " + vector32.z));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the size of a renderable in meters, you can do this:

```
Box box = (Box) transformableNode.getRenderable().getCollisionShape();
Vector3 renderableSize = box.getSize();
```

Once you have the size of the renderable, you can get the final size of the TransformableNode by multiplying the renderable's size by the scale:

```
Vector3 transformableNodeScale = transformableNode.getWorldScale();
  Vector3 finalSize =
      new Vector3(
          renderableSize.x * transformableNodeScale.x,
          renderableSize.y * transformableNodeScale.y,
          renderableSize.z * transformableNodeScale.z);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but only thing I want to achieve is to get the height of an object just like Google Measure App. Can you help me in that?

Comment: +1 since one cannot get simply center, extent, or size of an arbitrary looking renderable. This very tick casting the collision shape of a renderable to a box allows a developer to get exactly that. Google should put this post into their renderable documentation!